# Implementing Centralized QGIS Plugin Distribution via Custom Repository

Tags: qgis-3

In our company, the use of QGIS plugins must be restricted. We would now like to implement the distribution of plugins centrally and no longer via the user profile. To do this, we have created our own repository in which we make adjustments using the xml file. Now I would like to use qgis_global_settings.ini to specify that the plugins are to be used from the new repository and no longer via the user profile.
I have added the following to the qgis_global_settings.ini at the bottom:

```
[general]
pluginRepositories=file:////central_directory_for_everyone/plugins.xml
```

Then I set the variable in the cmd:

```
setx QGIS_GLOBAL_SETTINGS_FILE=C:\path\to\qgis_global_settings.ini
```

But no change so far. I can still add plugins freely in the profile folder. So my question: In which parameter must be inserted in the .ini file?? Is there anything else to consider regarding export?